# Look for duplicates in related tables

Tags: sql

I need some help with an sql query. I have two tables, Computer and Product connected by ComputerProduct. Now I want to know if there are any computers having the same Name with the same Product Primary Name and Secondary Name. Running the query on the following data would return both c1 and c2. 
How can I avoid duplicates within a table?

```
Computer
-----------------------
Id  Name    
c1  computer1
c2  computer1
c3  computer2

ComputerProduct
-----------------------
ComputerId  ProductId
c1          p1
c1          p2
c2          p1
c2          p2
c3          p1
c3          p2

Product
-----------------------
Id  Name        Type
p1  A1          Primary
p2  a1010       Secondary
```

Comment: Sample data is great, but don't forget to give us the expected result too!

Comment: `COUNT()` with `GROUP BY` should help

Comment: @jarlh, The result must return C1 and C2.

Comment: "I need some help with an sql query"   I don't see your query.   What error are you getting?

Comment: show the query you've tried so far

Comment: tag db pls (MSSQL, Oracle, Mysql, Postgresql or other?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried (on MSSQL) a query like the following (maybe it can be simplified...).

In the inner query, all combinations are extracted, using two joins for 'Primary' and 'Secondary' types.

Then the records are grouped and counted using computer.name and product's names.

With 'HAVING COUNT(*)>1' are extracted only records desired, ie having same computer name and products names.

Finally, are extracted only the ID corresponding to extracted computer.name(s) and products's names.

```
SELECT X.ID 
FROM COMPUTER X
INNER JOIN COMPUTERPRODUCT Y1 ON X.ID=Y1.COMPUTERID
INNER JOIN COMPUTERPRODUCT Y2 ON X.ID=Y2.COMPUTERID
INNER JOIN PRODUCT Z1 ON Y1.PRODUCTID = Z1.ID AND Z1.[TYPE] ='Primary'
INNER JOIN PRODUCT Z2 ON Y2.PRODUCTID = Z2.ID AND Z2.[TYPE] ='Secondary'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM  (SELECT A.NAME,  C1.NAME AS C1_NAME, C2.NAME AS C2_NAME, COUNT(*) AS RC
                        FROM COMPUTER A
                        INNER JOIN COMPUTERPRODUCT B1 ON A.ID=B1.COMPUTERID
                        INNER JOIN COMPUTERPRODUCT B2 ON A.ID=B2.COMPUTERID
                        INNER JOIN PRODUCT C1 ON B1.PRODUCTID = C1.ID AND C1.[TYPE]='Primary'
                        INNER JOIN PRODUCT C2 ON B2.PRODUCTID = C2.ID AND C2.[TYPE]='Secondary'
                        GROUP BY A.NAME, C1.NAME, C2.NAME
                        HAVING  COUNT(*) >1
                    ) E WHERE X.NAME = E.NAME AND Z1.NAME =C1_NAME AND Z2.NAME =C2_NAME);
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO COMPUTER VALUES ('c1','computer1');
INSERT INTO COMPUTER VALUES ('c2','computer1');
INSERT INTO COMPUTER VALUES ('c3','computer3');
INSERT INTO COMPUTER VALUES ('c4','computer1');

INSERT INTO COMPUTERPRODUCT VALUES ('c1','p1');
INSERT INTO COMPUTERPRODUCT VALUES ('c1','p2');
INSERT INTO COMPUTERPRODUCT VALUES ('c2','p1');
INSERT INTO COMPUTERPRODUCT VALUES ('c2','p2');
INSERT INTO COMPUTERPRODUCT VALUES ('c3','p1');
INSERT INTO COMPUTERPRODUCT VALUES ('c3','p2');
INSERT INTO COMPUTERPRODUCT VALUES ('c4','p1');
INSERT INTO COMPUTERPRODUCT VALUES ('c4','p3');

INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES ('p1','A1','Primary');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES ('p2','a1010','Secondary');
INSERT INTO PRODUCT VALUES ('p3','b2020','Secondary');
```

Output:

```
ID
c1
c2
```

Answer (score 1):

I have dealt with the same issue recently.

MySQL has the ability to make tables that don't accept duplicates.

You can alter your table, to remove duplicate values.

```
ALTER TABLE ComputerProduct
ADD UNIQUE (ComputerID);
```

IMPORTANT: DUPLICATE YOUR TABLE BEFORE MESSING WITH IT SO YOU DON'T RISK LOOSING ANY DATA...

All the best and Good Luck,
CrypticPug

Answer (score 1):

```
with dat
as (select c.id,c.name, p.prodtype,p.prodname
    from computer  c join computerProduct cp on c.id = cp.computerId
                     join product p on cp.productId = p.id)
select * from computer
where name in
(
    select name from (select id,name,prodname from dat where prodtype='Primary')x
    group by name
    having count(*)>1
    intersect
    select name from (select id,name,prodname from dat where prodtype='Secondary')x
    group by name
    having count(*)>1
)
```